# How can I add a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I [asked a question](https://superuser.com/questions/100313/help-needed-all-desktop-icons-have-disappeared) on Super User and I didn't receive an answer, so I would like to place a bounty.

On Stack Overflow I can select "start a bounty". But I cannot find something similar on my question on SU.

Am I just to blind to see it?

**EDIT**: my reputation on superuser.com is 215

Comment: You have to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A question has to be open for 2 days before you can set a bounty on it.

Comment: thanks. In didn't recognize that my question is such new ...